# Can't access alert from Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't access/find/click alert with `alert_is_present` or `driver.switch_to.alert` features in both Firefox and Chrome drivers.

Easy example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def test_easy():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # The same with Chrome
    driver.get("https://webcamtests.com/check")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "webcam-launcher"))).click()
    alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.alert_is_present())
```

The alert is visible:

[image: alert image]

but I'm getting `TimeoutException`

Similarly with the last line replaced by:

```py
    time.sleep(10)
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
```

I'm getting `NoAlertPresentException`.

```
Additional info:
Python 3.11
Selenium 4.8.2
Firefox Driver Version: 102.8.0
Chrome Driver Version: 110.0.5481.177
```

PS. No I don't want to ignore that alert or auto-click 'Allow'/'Block' button. Let's say I want to get alert text.

Comment: That's not a javacript alert.  It's a browser prompt and is outside the DOM (where Selenium can't get to it...)

Comment: @pcalkins is there any way to communicate with that?

Comment: You might try a "robot" style package... I think Python has one call py_robot?

Comment: I will check and if it ossible to use it, I will reply my question with description, thanks.